# Python-mysql: when to explicitly rollback a transaction

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Suppose, I have a modifying statement:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
# some code
affected_rows1 = cursor.execute(update_statement1, params1)
# some code
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

**Should I wrap the block of code with a `try ... except` and explicitly rollback a transaction when an exception is raised, and which MySQLdb exceptions should I catch to rollback?** I used to catch any `StandardError` in this case, but now I have a hesitation that the block of code would even need an explicit rollback at all.

The following example is slightly more difficult, and I understand that it does require an explicit rollback if the first update statement succeeded. Still, which exceptions should I catch in this case:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
# some code
affected_rows1 = cursor.execute(update_statement1, params1)
# some code
affected_rows2 = cursor.execute(update_statement2, params2)
#some code
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 20):

[This link](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/private/_mysql_exceptions-module.html) shows the various types of Errors that you can catch. `MySQLdb.Error` is the standard base class from which all other MySQL Errors are derived.

I usually use `MySQLdb.Error` because it lets you focus on errors relating to MySQLdb itself. By contrast `StandardError` will catch almost all the exceptions (not something you want if you want better debugging capability). Plus the use of `MySQLdb.Error` allows you to display the exact error message (**MySQL** error number and all) so that you can debug it faster.

Coming to the first part of the question, in case of database statements it is (usually) necessary to rollback transactions (if they are supported) in case of error.

The methodology that I follow is to wrap each `execute` statement in a try except clause (catching `MySQLdb.Error`) and using rollback if there is an an error before printing the error message and exiting.

However, there is a catch. In MySQLdb the changes that you make to DB are **not** actually written to the database until you explicilty call commit. So, logically, rollback is not necessary.

As an example,

```
conn = MySQLdb.connection(db=, host=, passwd=, user=)
cur = conn.cursor()
#Say you have a table X with one entry id = 1 and total = 50
cur.execute("update X set total = 70 where id = 1")
#Actual DB has not yet changed
cur.execute("update X set total = 80 where id = 1")
#Actual DB has still not changed
```

If you exit the program *without* commiting, the value in DB will still be 50 because you never called commit().

This is how you would ideally do it:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connection(db=, host=, passwd=, user=)
cur = conn.cursor()
#Say you have a table X with one entry id = 1 and total = 50
try:
    cur.execute("update X set total = 70 where id = 1")
except MySQLdb.Error,e:
    print e[0], e[1]
    conn.rollback()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    #print lengthy error description!!
    sys.exit(2)
    #Note: Value in table is still 50
#If you do conn.commit() here, value becomes 70 in table too!!
try:
    cur.execute("update X set total = 80 where id = 1")
except MySQLdb.Error,e:
    print e[0], e[1]
    conn.rollback()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    #print lengthy error description!!
    sys.exit(2)
    #Value in DB will be 
    #a) 50 if you didn't commit anywhere
    #b) 70 if you committed after first execute statement
conn.commit()
#Now value in DB is 80!!
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: A model StackOverflow answer (explanation + thorough working example). Superb.

Comment: If the commit() itself somehow fails, is rollback() needed to abandon the changes from the execute() so that the next commit() (which your example doesn't have) won't get them?

Comment: standard & safe practice that should be followed is: `try { start transaction; execute statements; commit transaction;} catch (Exception e) { perform rollback; } finally { close DB resources like statement; }` Also this point "_So, logically, rollback is not necessary._" if commit doesn't occurs is incorrect because the transaction will remains open and which could lead to serious issues like restart of another transaction will implicitly commit the prev one which you haven't closed (rolled back).

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, you should rollback transactions if you continue to use the same connection. Else everything before the error will get commit when you finish the transactions.
For the exception to catch, I always use `MySQLdb.Error` but I'm not sure that's correct.

Comment: I use even `StandardError`, and now am trying to understand what is correct to be sure.

Answer (score -1):

Its advised to wrap execute() in a sub. This is how i do it.

```
def executeSQL(self, stmt):
    cursor = self.dbHand.cursor()

    if not stmt.endswith(";"):
        stmt += ';'

    try:
        cursor.execute(stmt)
    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        self.logger.error("Caught MYSQL exception :%s: while executing stmt :%s:.\n"%(e,stmt))
        return False
```

Comment: I understand that, my question is though about conditions when to invoke implicit `rollback`

Comment: Can you clarify the benefit of this method please ?

Comment: As @Dikei mentioned rollback() if MySQLdb.Error exception is caught.

Comment: Dikei here are some advantages of warpping execute() in sub. One can do final check on sql(s), generate trace log etc.